# Bootstrap modal not triggered via jquery data-remote-load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement this fiddle script [multiple remote modal load](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ThLYb/), I can see the remote file in the network inspector loaded on click , but the modal is not triggered.

here is the code I'm trying to get working:

```
  <script>
 $('[data-load-remote]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
    if (remote) {
        $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
    }
});
    </script>
```

link to full code http://laravel.io/bin/2W3E2

Comment: Is your css pushing the modal off screen maybe?  I think I've seen this happen

Comment: I took a basic Bootstrap3 starter template, I tried to trigger a non remote  modal and it triggers.Forked it here : http://laravel.io/bin/mGJom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version fails because of "Cross-Origin Request Blocked".

The jsfiddle is working because it's loading from the same domain.  If you look at the url of the bottom right frame(not the url in the browser), it's the same domain as the urls it's trying to load with the buttons.

Your solution is in the warning error message shown in the Javascript console:

```
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

There are posts on this site about working with CORS(cross-origin resource sharing), but basically you would need to add a header on the remote urls, provided you have access to do so.

Adding code that works for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
    if(remote) {
        $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
    }
});

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/0/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 1</a>    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/1/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 2</a>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/2/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 3</a>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/3/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 4</a>



    <div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

bootstrap 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
    if(remote) {
        $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
    }
});

$('#openBtn').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
});

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/0/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 1</a>    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/1/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 2</a>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/2/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 3</a>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/3/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 4</a>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>



<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see this error in my console , I am working on my local host and the local files "remote files"  are in the same directory as the html page.

Comment: Button 1 and 4 are trying to call fiddle.jshell.net.  Localhost should work for 2 and 3.  I believe when I looked early it was a warning though, not an error

Comment: yes I removed those buttons calling fiddle.jshell.net , it still gives me  the fade transparent background of the modal but no modal window

Comment: HI this works for me , did you get it working  with bootstrap 3 I couldn't implement it with the latest B3 and Jquery?

Comment: bootstrap 3 sample added.  updated to min version required of jquery